# Maven exec bash script and save output as property

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I'm wondering if there exists a Maven plugin that runs a bash script and saves the results of it into a property.

My actual use case is to get the git source version.  I found one plugin available online but it didn't look well tested, and it occurred to me that a plugin as simple as the one in the title of this post is all I need.  Plugin would look something like:

```
<plugin>maven-run-script-plugin>
    <phase>process-resources</phase> <!-- not sure where most intelligent -->
    <configuration>
        <script>"git rev-parse HEAD"</script> <!-- must run from build directory -->
        <targetProperty>"properties.gitVersion"</targetProperty>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Of course necessary to make sure this happens before the property will be needed, and in my case I want to use this property to process a source file.

Comment: What about the buildnumber-maven-plugin ?

Answer (score 5):

I think you could utilize `gmaven` plugin for this task:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
    <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>execute</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <properties>
                    <script>git rev-parse HEAD</script>
                </properties>
                <source>
                    def command = project.properties.script
                    def process = command.execute()
                    process.waitFor()

                    project.properties.gitVersion = process.in.text
                </source>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

After execution of this script you should be able to refer to `${gitVersion}` property.